# How deploy application to eks from gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gitlab, pipeline, amazon-eks

I have a gitlab account and EKS cluster running in aws. Now i have to deploy application to eks cluster from gitlab.

For now i have idea like from gitlab push the image to ecr, from ecr push it to Eks but i dont have any idea to how to that.
Any kind of documentation or youtube links will very helpfull to me

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to deploy Argo CD in your EKS cluster and connect it to your github organization or repositories

https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

[image: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/assets/argocd_architecture.png]